# iOS: Processing UI events in NSRunLoop

Tags: ios, user-interface

I'm working on an iPad app that needs to spawn a dialog mid-function for some user interaction. In order to wait for the dialog, I run an NSRunLoop, however, this is preventing events on the dialog from being processed. This is how I spawn the dialog:

```
NSArray* listOfCompatibleTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[listOfCompatibleTypesAndSizesAsSet allObjects]];

[secondaryImplantChooserDialog setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFormSheet];
[secondaryImplantChooserDialog setDefinesPresentationContext:YES];                
[self presentViewController:secondaryImplantChooserDialog animated:NO completion:nil];
```

And the runloop is like this:

```
NSRunLoop* runLoop = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];
while (secondaryImplantChooserDialog.fDialogDone != YES)
{
    [runLoop runUntilDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0.01]];
}
```

The dialog box has a popover that contains a tableview. When I comment out the runloop, the table view's didSelectRowAtIndexPath(…) method gets called. When the loop is active, however, that method doesn't get called until the dialog gets dismissed.

I realize this isn't exactly an iOS-kosher design, so I should probably refactor it, but I was wondering if there was any way to process UI events while the runloop is active.

Comment: Polling is very rarely a good solution.  Perhaps you could use an `NSLock` to block until the dialog is done?

Comment: Any thoughts on how to use it? I've never used NSLock before.

Comment: It is hard to say without understanding more of the structure of your program.  I am unclear as to why you have a problem in the first place - presenting a modal view should prevent any interaction with the rest of your UI elements and the first view controller should be the delegate for the modal view so it knows when the dialog has been dismissed

Comment: Ah, well the issue is I have some code after that runloop in the same function that spawns the dialog. The issue is that the dialog spawns, and the rest of the function executes. My goal was to try and prevent further execution until the user made a choice.

Comment: I would try and refactor your code, perhaps splitting the method in two.  I don't think that the NSLock approach will work because of threading issues.

Comment: Understood, I suspected I would need to. Thank you for the feedback. Is there a way to flag your comment as the answer?

Comment: No, I can post an answer if you like

Comment: Yes, I think your comment is the way to go on this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Polling is very rarely a good solution, particularly in a user-interactive environment like an iOS app.  The functionality you are looking for is a semaphore - where you can block execution in one part of your app until another has completed.  You can do this with [Grand Central Dispatch](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/ThreadMigration/ThreadMigration.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH105-SW12) but this is probably adding complexity when a better solution is to re-factor.

From what I understand you have a method which is performing some calculation or business-logic and it determines that additional information is needed. You could refactor something like:

```
   if ([self haveEnoughInfo]) {
       [self performFinalCalc];
   } else {
       [self gatherMoreInformation];  // Use a delegate or completion block to invoke [self performFinalCalc] once more information is gathered
   }
```